GridDB Error 30007 CP_LOG_FILE_WRITE_FAILED When Writing to Log File
I'm developing a Java application that utilizes GridDB for data storage. Recently, I've encountered the following error during runtime:
30007 CP_LOG_FILE_WRITE_FAILED ERROR Writing to log file failed. A 
failure may have occurred in the storage at the log file storage 
location.
Check whether a physical failure has occurred in storing the 
transaction log file storage location.

The application initializes a GridDB client and performs standard CRUD operations. The server hosting the application has ample disk space, and other services can write to the designated log directory without any issues. This error started appearing after deploying the latest version of my application.
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;

public class GridDBLogger {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
            GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactory.getInstance();
            GridStore store = factory.getGridStore(new GridStoreFactoryProperties());

            ContainerInfo containerInfo = new ContainerInfo();
            containerInfo.setName("TransactionLogs");
            containerInfo.setType(ContainerType.COLLECTION);
            containerInfo.setRowDefinition(MyLog.class);

            Container<String, MyLog> container = store.putContainer(containerInfo);

            // Insert a log entry
            MyLog logEntry = new MyLog("User123", "Performed a transaction.");
            container.put(logEntry);

            // Close the store
            store.close();
        } catch (GridStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyLog {
    private String userId;
    private String action;

    public MyLog(String userId, String action) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.action = action;
}

}
I've Tried:
Checked Disk Space: Verified that there's sufficient disk space on the server.
Permissions: Ensured that the application has the necessary write permissions to the log directory.
Restarted Services: Restarted both the GridDB cluster and the application to rule out transient issues.
Log Directory Path: Confirmed that the log file storage path is correctly configured in GridDB properties.
Antivirus/Firewall: Disabled antivirus and firewall temporarily to ensure they're not blocking write operations.
Despite these attempts, the error persists.
Additional Information:
GridDB Version: 5.0.0
Java Version: OpenJDK 11
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Deployment: Docker container
Has anyone encountered the 30007 CP_LOG_FILE_WRITE_FAILED error in GridDB? What are the potential causes, and how can I resolve this issue to ensure that my application can write to the GridDB log files successfully?
